# D3 simple line graph with my own data

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I am learning D3. I found a simple line graph example on the internet and I am trying to do it with my own data. In stead of the data.csv being in a seperate file as in the example I placed it in the html script like this:

```
var data            =   [
    { date: 2008, num: 54248 }, { date: 2009, num: 54446 },
    { date: 2010, num: 54731 }, { date: 2011, num: 55212 },
    { date: 2012, num: 55595 }, { date: 2013, num: 56165 },
    { date: 2014, num: 56690 }, { date: 2015, num: 56929 },
    { date: 2016, num: 57005 }, { date: 2017, num: 57010 }
];
```

But now all the other things are inside the d3.csv() function. Like the x.domain, y.domain and the svg.append's. I dont need the d3.csv function since I dont have a csv anymore. But with what function do I replace it? Assuming it is as simple as replacing the function that is.

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.date = parseTime(d.date);
      d.num = +d.num;
  });

  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.num; })]);

  // Add the valueline path.
  svg.append("path")
      .data([data])
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", valueline);

  // Add the X Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // Add the Y Axis
  svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

});
```

Comment: I think you could just remove the csv function parameters, no need for a function

Comment: it works! oh thats so simple. Thanks

Comment: doesn't work for me